# Windows Phone 7 + Add multiple values in one key in isolated storage.

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can I add multiple values in one key in isolated storage settings? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array with values and store that in the value.

```
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["key"] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: Keep in mind you can store anything that will serialize, that includes your own custom types...